# linux command and shell script for remote transfer file

Tags: shell

I have setup the passpahse between local server and remote server

and I try this command directly in linux (where file is a single file and $remote is the remote server)

> scp $file root@$remote:/tmp/

it work fine

and I try to write the command in shell script and call it on linux , it also work

but if I try to call the shell script from php, it just output the error (from my logging)

> Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
>
> Host key verification failed.

How come?

Answer (score 1):

Your php does not run as you, or at least has a changed root, so it sees its home as /var/www/ which does not contain the .ssh folder (and needed files).

If you add a .ssh in /var/www, make sure the .ssh is owned by the user that php runs as and that the files have correct attributes (who can read/write to the files).

Comment: i guess so, how should i config it

Comment: Can you add a private and public key to the www folder? Or were you asking for how to run the php as you? The latter I'd recommend against.

Comment: i try to copy, but after copy and run , it occur permission denied, as the directory has already set as same as the original one, any other way, like run php as you?

Comment: Check which user php runs as and make sure the access settings on the .ssh (end everything in it is correct) and owned by the php user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this first in your Script:

```
whoami
```

If the User is `www-data`, create a Directory  .ssh in `/var/www`. Then give this Directory `/var/www/.ssh` the Owner and Group of the User, your PHP runs.

For me (Perl-Script) this works well, although there's nothing in the Directory .ssh after starting my Script (sFTP).

Answer (score 1):

create a dummy directory in `/var/www`, then run `mkdir /var/www/.ssh`
and `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh`

This should fix your problem.
`shell_exec('/usr/bin/scp $file root@$remote:/tmp/')`

Answer (score 0):

Your normal user account has the ssh keys stored (by default, they are stored in `$HOME/.ssh`) not the web server user which is why the command runs fine when you use it in the shell and not from the browser. The browser process tries to create the `.ssh` directory in its home directory and fails to do so, and thus cannot continue.

You should be using [`ssh2_scp_send`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) to do this from PHP.

Comment: except scp, my shell script do many thing, like packing file and then send to remote server.. , so i dont think ssh2_scp_send can do it